# Changes in the web_studio module

Tags: odoo, enterprise, odoo-15

I make changes to one js file inside the web_studio module itself, but the changes are not applied
I work at Odoo Enterprise
I rebooted the server, reinstalled the module and updated it - all without success
I'm asking for help((((

Comment: please provide your odoo version and your code to enable good investigations

Comment: You can try clearing your browser's cache.